# Get count of children from each parent.SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 databases that are supposed to be identical. For some tables I need to compare and count how many children a parent got and compare this with the  identical database.

Is what I have done below the correct way to get count of children?
Is there a better way?

Put together below a sample with some dummy data."Employee" table with addresses
Comparing how many addresses each employee has.

The desired result is what I already get, but I'm wondering again if there is a better way to do this.

Desired result:

```
EmployeeId  TotalAddressesA TotalAddressesB
1           4               1
2           2               5
```

Setup:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EmployeeDBA') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #EmployeeDBA
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EmployeeDBAddressA') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #EmployeeDBAddressA
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EmployeeDBB') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #EmployeeDBB
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EmployeeDBAddressB') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #EmployeeDBAddressB

    CREATE TABLE #EmployeeDBA
    (   [EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Surname] [varchar](50) NULL
    )

    CREATE TABLE #EmployeeDBB
    (   [EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Surname] [varchar](50) NULL
    )
    CREATE TABLE #EmployeeDBAddressA
    (   [EmployeeAddressId] [int] NOT NULL,
         [EmployeeId][int] NOT NULL,
        [Addresss] [varchar](50) NULL,
    )
    CREATE TABLE #EmployeeDBAddressB
    (   [EmployeeAddressId] [int] NOT NULL,
         [EmployeeId][int] NOT NULL,
        [Addresss] [varchar](50) NULL,
    )

    INSERT #EmployeeDBA (EmployeeId,Name,Surname)
    VALUES(1,'Jo','Bloggs'),(2,'Mark','Smith')

    INSERT #EmployeeDBB (EmployeeId,Name,Surname)
    VALUES(1,'Jo','Bloggs'),(2,'Mark','Smith')

    INSERT #EmployeeDBAddressA(EmployeeAddressId,EmployeeId,Addresss)
    VALUES(1,1,'Address1ForEmployee1'),
    (2,1,'Address2ForEmployee1'),
    (3,1,'Address3ForEmployee1'), 
    (4,1,'Address4ForEmployee1'),
    (5,2,'Address1ForEmployee2'),
    (6,2,'Address2ForEmployee2')      


    INSERT #EmployeeDBAddressB(EmployeeAddressId,EmployeeId,Addresss)
    VALUES(1,1,'Address1ForEmployee1'),
    (2,2,'Address1ForEmployee2'),
    (3,2,'Address2ForEmployee2'),
    (4,2,'Address3ForEmployee2'),
    (5,2,'Address4ForEmployee2'),
    (6,2,'Address5ForEmployee2')


    --BELOW IS WHAT I AM QUERYING IF IT'S BEST WAY TO FIND COUNT OF CHILDREN FOR EACH PARENT.
    ;WITH CTEA
         AS ( SELECT A.EmployeeId,
                     TotalCountA = ( 
                                          SELECT COUNT(EmployeeId)
                                          FROM #EmployeeDBAddressA b
                                          WHERE b.EmployeeId = a.EmployeeId)
              FROM #EmployeeDBA A
              GROUP BY A.EmployeeId ),
         CTEB
         AS (SELECT A.EmployeeId,
                     TotalCountB = ( 
                                          SELECT COUNT(EmployeeId)
                                          FROM #EmployeeDBAddressB b
                                          WHERE b.EmployeeId = a.EmployeeId)
              FROM #EmployeeDBB A
              GROUP BY A.EmployeeId )

        --is this the way to compare totals betwen 2 tables   

        SELECT A.EmployeeId,A.TotalCountA,B.TotalCountB
        FROM CTEA A
                LEFT JOIN CTEB B ON A.EmployeeId = B.EmployeeId
        WHERE ISNULL(A.TotalCountA, 0) <> ISNULL(B.TotalCountB, 0);


    DROP TABLE #EmployeeDBA
    DROP TABLE #EmployeeDBAddressA
    DROP TABLE #EmployeeDBB
    DROP TABLE #EmployeeDBAddressB
```

Comment: Use `FULL JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. Other than that, the current query seems to be correct. It can be simplified, but it is correct.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov thanks for your comment I was wondering about the full join .is this because i might not have any records in my main table?.How would you simplify it?I am intrigued.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `FULL JOIN` when joining CTEs instead of `LEFT JOIN` to catch missing Employees in both tables. In your current variant with `LEFT JOIN`, if `EmployeeDBA` has no rows, but `EmployeeDBB` has rows, your query would return empty result set, even though the tables are different.

In the CTE I'd join two tables instead of calculating `COUNT` in subquery. Though, it is likely that optimizer would generate the same plan.

```
WITH 
CTEA
AS
(
    SELECT
        Emp.EmployeeId
        ,COUNT(Addr.EmployeeId) AS TotalCountA
    FROM
        #EmployeeDBA AS Emp
        LEFT JOIN #EmployeeDBAddressA AS Addr ON Addr.EmployeeId = Emp.EmployeeId
        -- LEFT JOIN for those Employees that don't have addresses
    GROUP BY Emp.EmployeeId
)
,CTEB
AS
(
    SELECT
        Emp.EmployeeId
        ,COUNT(Addr.EmployeeId) AS TotalCountA
    FROM
        #EmployeeDBB AS Emp
        LEFT JOIN #EmployeeDBAddressB AS Addr ON Addr.EmployeeId = Emp.EmployeeId
        -- LEFT JOIN for those Employees that don't have addresses
    GROUP BY Emp.EmployeeId
)
SELECT
    COALESCE(CTEA.EmployeeId, CTEB.EmployeeId) AS EmployeeId
    ,CTEA.TotalCountA
    ,CTEB.TotalCountB
FROM
    CTEA
    FULL JOIN CTEB ON CTEA.EmployeeId = CTEB.EmployeeId
    -- FULL JOIN to catch missing Employees in both tables
WHERE
    ISNULL(CTEA.TotalCountA, 0) <> ISNULL(CTEB.TotalCountB, 0)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
   SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT EmployeeId
        FROM #EmployeeDBA
        UNION
        SELECT EmployeeId
        FROM #EmployeeDBB) AS C
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalCountA
        FROM #EmployeeDBAddressA WHERE EmployeeId = C.EmployeeId
    ) AS A
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalCountB
        FROM #EmployeeDBAddressB WHERE EmployeeId = C.EmployeeId
    ) AS B
```